# Unixy way of sorting C prototypes alphabetically

Tags: c, sorting, unix, function-prototypes

Suppose you have a list of C function prototypes, one per line, like

```
void   foo(void);
struct baz *zap(void (*callback)(void));
long long blurb(long i);
long double sinus(long double arg);
sometype_t somefunc(void);
```

Sorted by function name the result is

```
long long blurb(long i);
void   foo(void);
long double sinus(long double arg);
sometype_t somefunc(void);
struct baz *zap(void (*callback)(void));
```

As far as I read the sort(1) manual, this cannot be sorted using -k options, since the function identifier is sometimes the second word, sometimes the third (lets ignore cases where the function identifier is even further to the right, as when structs are spelled out).

But I know that the function identifier is the string before the first '(' token on the line. Does anyone know a unixy way to sort this? **Unixy := a one line filter/pipe**. I could probably hack up an ugly perl solution deleting the uninteresting left part, sorting, and restoring the left part, but that's nowhere near a one-liner.

Comment: Why would you ever want to group functions by the first letter instead of their functionality?

Comment: Maybe use awk to swap/copy the function name to the first position then pipe it to sort so you are sorting `foo: void foo(void)..."

Comment: Of course in perl **everything** can be a one liner - just sometimes it is a **very** long line!

Comment: @Lundin Because the functions already have name prefixes like fooStart, fooStop, fooGet, fooSet. In addition "same functionality" is a pretty arbitrary and ambiguous criterion. Alphabetical leaves no ambiguity where a prototype is to be inserted. I like hard and fast rules in a case like this where order does not matter to the compiler.

Comment: Note that the standard C function `signal()` has a prototype like `void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);` which doesn't match your expectations.  There isn't a simple way to do this in a one-liner — it isn't a simple problem because the C syntax isn't simple.  In fact, I don't think there's a simple way to do it in a multiple line script — simply analyzing the lines to get the function name extracted is hard work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The unixy thing then may be to offload the tricky part to the `cdecl explain` program which always begins with `declare signal as ...` no matter how complicated the prototype is. I'll grant any contestant at least 134 characters for a line :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I know that the function identifier is the string before the first '(' token on the line

The usual way I go about such sorting tasks, is to use `sed` with a good regex to insert a unique separator into the input, that I can later use with `sort`. After sorting the separator can be removed. So:

1. Insert `(` in front of the function identifier.
2. Sort by second column using `(` as separator.
3. Remove the first `(` from the line.

The following:

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\)/(\1/' | sort -t'(' -k2 | sed 's/(//'
```

with the following input:

```
void   foo(void);
struct baz *zap(void (*callback)(void));
long long blurb(long i);
long double sinus(long double arg);
sometype_t somefunc(void);
```

[outputs on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/LongtermAdmirableSlash):

```
long long blurb(long i);
void   foo(void);
long double sinus(long double arg);
sometype_t somefunc(void);
struct baz *zap(void (*callback)(void));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [the Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
perl -pE 'm!([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\(! && print "$1:"' | # decorate
sort |                                                    # sort
perl -pE 's!^([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*):!!'                 # undecorate
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `awk`, `tr`, `cut` and `sort`:

```
tr -s ' ' file | cut -d '(' -f 1 | awk '{print($NF" "$0)}' | cut -d ' ' -f1 | tr -d '*' | sort
```

1. Squeeze space repeats
2. Cut first field from line using ( delimiter
3. Get last field, function name, and copy first
4. Cut just first field using space delimiter
5. Delete all *, pointer return character
6. Sort

Comment: That leaves only the function identifiers. The idea is to sort the whole input by lines.